# 続けて回っている versus 回り続けている

Tags: grammar

Is there any difference between 続けて回っている and 回り続けている?

Answer (score 2):

Yes!  The first one means to "continue  and then turn".  The second one means to "continue turning".

Answer (score 1):

続けて回っている can mean that you have followed someone who started to spin and are spinning yourself, beside the same thing as 回り続けている.